# Git Directory Permissions Always 000

Tags: git, file-permissions, git-plumbing

By messing around with Git objects, I've found that the tree entries within a tree object always have these permissions.

```
040000 DirEntry hash
```

The 04 means that it is a directory, but the permissions are 000. Does this mean that Git does not store tree permissions, or is that how Unix works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. Git does not store permissions for tree objects, even though directories Unix filesystems do have them. For files, git only stores the executable bit (+x). All files are assumed to be readable and writable. This means that only modes you'll see for blobs are `100644` (not executable) and `100755` (executable).

For more information, see e.g. the documentation on [what git stores in the index file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt#L63).

Comment: Correct link is https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitformat-index.txt